# What is NM cable with green jacket?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am trying to update a two prong receptacle to a three prong. In the receptacle box is what looks like NM cable but it appears pretty old and has a green colored sheathing.

Is this an acceptable “romex” alternative? I haven’t installed my three prong yet, but will install and check for ground/neutral/hot.

I am wondering if I should snake a new romex cable or if this will be ok for a general bedroom receptacle.

[image]

Comment: The sheath is "old-style (fabric visible) but the wire insulation looks modern enough, plastic in good shape. I would fix that half-fast ground-to-the-box connection, which appears to be wrapped around a mounting screw, while the "GR" threaded hole for a 10-32 ground screw is notably empty.

Comment: Code does not specify a color for NM aka Romex sheathing.  The white-yellow-orange thing you see in the stores is just something one manufacturer decided to do and others copied.  One builder in Las Vegas is reputed to have custom-ordered pink Romex, and worked with all the local scrap companies so they call the cops on anybody who shows up with pink Romex :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering if I should snake a new romex cable or if this will be
> ok for a general bedroom receptacle.

I  do not see a need for a new cable.

The metal box is grounded, (*attaching the receptacle to the metal box provides a ground*).

The wires appear to be of sufficient gauge.

All should be good.

Comment: Attaching the receptacle to the metal box supplies a ground *only if* it has hard metal-metal yoke contact, or if the recep is labeled "self-grounding" (meaning it has a wiper brush that contacts the screw threads).  They can't ground via the screw  heads like switches can, perhaps because fighting a stiff plug, you could lift the recep off the screw heads.